# Solving the equation $\frac{2x+3}{x+1} = \frac{2x+2}{x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a college student and I've got a problem solving this:

$$\frac{2x+3}{x+1} = \frac{2x+2}{x-1}.$$

Since neither the numerators nor the denominators are equal, I figured that $(2x+3)(x-1) = (x+1)(2x+2)$ would provide me with a suitable $x$.

However calculating this I found that $x = -\frac13$ while my answer sheet states that $x = -\frac23$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you certain you have written the problem correctly?  My answer differs both from yours and from the answer sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answers everyone, I'm sorry about the answer from the answer sheet being wrong, it should have been -(5/3)

Comment: Hopefully this doesn't sound to condescending, but if you are ever unsure about a solution to an equation, often the easiest thing to do is just substitute the solution back in and see if everything works out. Indeed, it's probably not a bad practice even when you're not unsure about the solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have by cross multiplying that,$$2(x+1)^{2} = 2x^{2} + x -3$$ $$ \Longrightarrow 2x^{2}+4x+2 = 2x^{2} + x -3$$ $$ \Longrightarrow 3x = -5 \Rightarrow x= -\frac{5}{3}$$

Comment: Oops, The answer sheet answer should be -5/3 indeed, It's just that I wrote it down like this: -1(1/3) it figures that should go wrong. Looking at your anwers, I think I know what I did wrong. I added 2 instead of subtracting it from -3. Subtracting gives 3x = -5 so that's it.

Answer (score 2):

There’s nothing wrong with your basic approach, but you seem to have solved the equation $(2x+3)(x-1)=(x+1)(2x+2)$ incorrectly. After multiplying out both sides, you should have $$2x^2+x-3=2x^2+4x+2\;,$$ which simplifies progressively to $$\begin{align*}
x-3&=4x+2\;,\\
-3&=3x+2\;,\\
-5&=3x\;,\text{ and}\\
x&=-\frac53.
\end{align*}$$

Substituting this into the original equation yields $$\begin{align*}
\frac{2\left(-\frac53\right)+3}{-\frac53+1} &\stackrel{?}= \frac{2\left(-\frac53\right)+2}{-\frac53-1}\\
\frac{-\frac13}{-\frac23} &\stackrel{?}= \frac{-\frac43}{-\frac83}\\
\frac12&=\frac12.
\end{align*}$$

In other words, both you and the answer sheet are wrong.